# AngularJS select > option group by

Tags: angularjs, filter

```
$scope.accounts = [ 
     {id: 1, name: 'Tommy',status:'premium'}, 
     {id: 2, name: 'Alexander',status:'free'},
     {id: 3, name: 'Lorem',status:'banned'},
     {id: 4, name: 'Ipsum',status:'premium'} 
     {id: 5, name: 'Dot sit',status:'Y'} 
 ];
```

How can I adjust dynamically to the situation in this json output?

for example, multiple data in groupby

```
<select>
  <option>premium</option>
  <option>free</option>
  <option>banned</option>
  <option>y</option>
</select>
```

(My English is bad )

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I want to  account>status in merge/group write  select>option

Comment: That doesn't mean anything `account>status` is not a verb.

Comment: I'm filtering on the table . I do not need to filter by status . output [premium,free,banned,premium,Y] I want to multiple 'premium' merge

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-options="item as item.status for item in (accounts | unique: 'status')"></select>
```

You need to include the filter from https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/tree/master/modules/filters/unique